# Rails3 seeding data with an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Good day lovely people,

I wanted to do the following with my seed data but I'm getting mass assignment errors which is fine.

```
#Seeds.rb

Category.create(name: 'Top hats', category_id: '44')

#Mass-assignment error
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category_id
```

But if I setup the seed data in a CSV file, I can import successfully using the following:

```
#Seeds.rb

require 'csv'

  CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join("category.csv"), headers: true) do |row|
    BusinessCategory.create! do |category|
      category.id = row[0]
      category.name = row[1]
    end
  end
```

Also, this works in the Rails console:

```
#Rails console

category = Category.new
category.name = 'Top hat'
category.id = 42
```

I know it can be easily fixed by setting an `attr_accessible :category_id` in the Category model but 1) I wanted to know more about why this happens and 2) I don't think it's neccessary to put it as accessible since I'm just importing the data and no need to change it?

Thanks in advance.

Happy days :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just update the code in `seeds.rb` to not do a mass assignment (aka pass a hash or attributes)

So instead of

```
Category.create(name: 'Top hats', category_id: '44')
```

do

```
category = Category.new (name: 'Top hat')
category.category_id = 42 # the irb code said 'id' but in your example its category_id
category.save
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Monica. I think that's probably my best bet since I only have a few records to iterate through. Much appreciated.